# How to split a array to some sub-arrays with objective minimizing sum of square?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

I have a array `[a1, a2, a3,..., an]`, I want to split this array into some sub-arrays(i.e 3 sub-arrays) with constraints that each sub-array must be continuous.For example, `sub-arr1=[a1, a2,..., a8], sub-arr2=[a9, a10,..., a17],sub-arr1=[a18, a19,..., an],`  and I want to minimize sum of each aub-array's variance, say

```
min sum(sum((some element in sub_i - avg_value in sub_i)^2)) and the outer sum is to sum all sub-arrays.
```

Now, I don't know how to solve this problem efficiently, Thx.

Comment: Please first define the constraint of the problem, i.e., max value of n and max number of sub-arrays, because if you could get the number of sub arrays equal to n, then you always reach to 0 as the minimum value.

Comment: @Alireza For example, 3 sub-arrays for a array with length 96,I already know the total sub-arrays number.

Comment: If you need only 3 sub-arrays, use simple 3 nested loops and the complexity would be O(N^3) where max value of N is 96. You only need less than 1 second for waiting to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

I find a paper to solve my problem, [solver](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/20450634_Algorithms_for_the_Optimal_Identification_of_Segment_Neighborhoods)

Comment: Could you implement this?